# flex builder 3 plugin error files

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, plugins, builder

where does Flex builder 3 plugin output error messages? I'm trying to import wsdl however i keep getting an "unable to load wsdl" message.

Ive tried creating a trusted certificate in the jdk cacerts file however no success and could do with seeing what is actually the problem. I have looked under the Program Files/Adobe/Flex Builder 3 plugin/ folder but cant find anything which has been updated in the time frame ive been seeing the exceptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update to Flash Builder 4.1
2. Add crossdomain.xml to your server with WSDL
3. check back into your IDE
4. Let us know)